# Error @signUp: [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'firebase.createUser')]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo

I'm trying to implement my signUp screen here is the signup handle that is being called, the signup page calls, and pass in the value to my context page.

```
const handleSignup = async () => {
    setLoading(true)

      const user = { fullname, email, password, profilePhoto};

    try {

      const createdUser = await firebase.createUser(user)

      setUser({ ...createdUser, isLoggedIn: true });
    } catch (error) {

      console.log("Error @signUp: ", error);

    } finally {

      setLoading(false)

    }
  };
```

the firebaseContext page then takes in the value that has been passed in creates the account

```
    const FirebaseContext = createContext();
    
    if(!firebase.apps.length){
        firebase.initializeApp(auth);
    }
    
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    
    const Firebase = {
        getCurrentUser: () => {
            return firebase.auth().currentUser
        },
    
        createUser: async (user) => {
            try{
                 await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);
                 const uid = Firebase.getCurrentUser().uid;
    
                 let profilePhotoUrl = "default";
    
                 await db.collection("users").doc(uid).set({
                     fullname: user.fullname,
                     email: user.email, 
                     profilePhotoUrl
                 })
    
                 if(user.profilePhoto){
                    profilePhotoUrl = await Firebase.uploadProfilePhoto(user.profilePhoto);
                 }
    
                 delete user.password;
    
                 return { ...user, profilePhotoUrl, uid};
    
            }catch(error){
                console.log("Error @createUser", error.message);
            }
        },
```

Exporting the file

```
import { FirebaseContext, FirebaseProvider, Firebase } from './FirebaseContext';
import { UserContext, UserProvider } from './UserContext';


export { FirebaseContext, Firebase, FirebaseProvider, UserContext, UserProvider };
```

Importing the file

```
import { FirebaseContext } from "../context";
```

Comment: Is there anything more to the error? A code stacktrace? Any more context/detail regarding what of `firebase.createUser` is undefined or not an object? I notice you use `Firebase` in the firebase context, but in the signup code it's `firebase`. Have you ensured you are not mixing your `Firebase` object with the Firebase `firebase` object?

Comment: @DrewReese I have rechecked my code and when I change it to `Firebase.createUser`, I get another error saying it cannot be found. I have also rechecked my code to insure I am calling the right object

Comment: Do you have more of the error logging? Is there a code stacktrace? What debugging have you done? Have you set a breakpoint and stepped through the code to see where it breaks?

Comment: @DrewReese I used DevTool for debugging and it says createUser/created user is undefined

Comment: Is the `return { ...user, profilePhotoUrl, uid};` line running? It returns a defined object. Is it the `user` value here that you are trying to spread that is undefined?

Comment: @DrewReese no it's not the user that is undefined it complaining about `createUser(user)` it don't it recognize it. It can't seem to find the function itself

Comment: Not sure if it has to do with the way I exported it or not